# What is the mechanism behind polling SCM in Jenkins?

Tags: svn, jenkins

As I understand, configuring Jenkins to periodically to detect changes in the repository is as simple as enabling the "Poll SCM" option and setting up the schedule in a cronjob manner.

However, in the specific case of Subversion, I would like to understand what is going on under the hood: How does Jenkins detect whether they have been changes in the repository?

Simply by parsing a `svn status` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses SCM plugin internally written in JAVA. This library has implementation for all SCM tools including SVN. It basically executes pollChanges() in the library which internally check the last modified time from AbstractProject.getLastBuild().getTimestamp() and identifies there this a new change set or not and trigger build accordingly. Reference: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Polling+for+changes.

Comment: Thanks, I see. Is the SCM plugin you are talking about the Subversion plugin which is installed by default with Jenkins or is it some other general SCM plugin?

Comment: Yes, Subversion plugin is used internally in SCM plugin to achieve this.